# install local package in tox unencumbered by previous install from GitHub

Tags: python, pip, pytest, conda, tox

### Question

How to use tox to install a the local package without it refering to a random time when I installed the pacakge from GitHub?

### Context

In [this PR](https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse/pull/40), I'm trying to build and test my package, `dbt-synapse`, before publishing a new minor version to PyPI. At some point (rookie move), I think I tried installing the package directly from a specific GitHub commit with the below line.

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse.git@345d7cafcb08bac25d23867a2e22c0e9b741f603#egg=dbt_synapse
```

[Here's a gist of the `requirements.txt`, `tox.ini`, `setup.py` and some other files](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/fe376e80cd2b0420c21be5ab4936fc68)

When I call `tox -e integration-synapse` to kick off the tests, having listing the actual package in the deps as `-e.` compared to just `.`, causes the package to be installed from GitHub (see the  `integration-synapse installed:` line below, shortened for clarity)!

when deps has just `.`, however it lists this as having been installed (which also doesn't seem right): `dbt-synapse @ file:///Users/anders.swanson/repos/dbt-synapse`.

Unfortunately, neither are giving me what I know should be happening.

```
integration-synapse recreate: /Users/anders.swanson/repos/dbt-synapse/.tox/integration-synapse
integration-synapse installdeps: -rrequirements.txt, -e.
integration-synapse installed: [...],-e git+https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse.git@345d7cafcb08bac25d23867a2e22c0e9b741f603#egg=dbt_synapse,[...]
integration-synapse runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='1932234374'
integration-synapse runtests: commands[0] | /bin/bash -c '/Users/anders.swanson/repos/dbt-synapse/.tox/integration-synapse/bin/python -m pytest -v test/integration/synapse.dbtspec'
======================================================================================================================================== test session starts =========================================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.12, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /Users/anders.swanson/repos/dbt-synapse/.tox/integration-synapse/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/anders.swanson/repos/dbt-synapse
plugins: dbt-adapter-0.4.0
collected 1 item
```

#### `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = integration-synapse

[testenv:integration-synapse]
basepython = python3
commands = /bin/bash -c '{envpython} -m pytest -v test/integration/synapse.dbtspec'
passenv = DBT_SYNAPSE_DB DBT_SYNAPSE_PORT DBT_SYNAPSE_PWD DBT_SYNAPSE_SERVER DBT_SYNAPSE_UID
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
    -e.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start from a clean state, you can you can delete the hidden `.tox` folder and start from scratch.

Also, you can run `tox -r` which will **recreate** the environemnts.

In order to test the code from your local development environment, you do not have to include your package in the deps list (`-e.`). `tox` will build the package from your `setup.py`.

Well.. it would. But in your `tox.ini` you specified `skipsdist = True` which afaik means `tox` should not build the package.

There are some more issues in your `tox.ini`, e.g. unit and flake8 envs do nothing.

Why do you use the `/bin/bash -c` construct?

Unfortunately, I am missing some header files, so I cannot run your `tox.ini` file, but I would create a `tox.ini` file like this...

```
[tox]
envlist = py36,py37,py38,py39,integration-synapse,flake8

[testenv]
deps = whatever needed for your unit tests
commands = python -m pytest ...unit tests...

[testenv:integration-synapse]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-dbt-adapter
commands =
    python -m pytest -v test/integration/synapse.dbtspec
passenv = DBT_SYNAPSE_DB DBT_SYNAPSE_PORT DBT_SYNAPSE_PWD DBT_SYNAPSE_SERVER DBT_SYNAPSE_UID

[testenv:flake8]
skipsdist = True
deps = flake8
commands = flake8 setup.py ... (and more)
```